# Android Gradle: how to builds separate versions automatically for different languages?

Tags: android, gradle

I have folders for specific languages:
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-en-xhdpi
values
values-en

I want to be able builds separate apk for default language and for EN language. How can I do it?
Note: in drawable-en-xhdpi I have only one image that have languages specific text.

Comment: Why do you want separate apks?

Comment: We have an app that supports over 30 languages and we don't have separate apks.

Comment: My customer want the separate apk for each language.